# Passing Database into Repository to Get the Right MongoDB Collection

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, micronaut

The way I want to layout my data in Mongo is:

```
account
  - sites
  - orders
  - etc
```

where `account` will be a UUID. So it might end up looking like...

```
a131258b-0ae1-442a-ba57-37d1ed4cd784
  - sites
  - orders
  - etc
71af278b-0cb6-44f0-9f75-4c3f3bb262a7
  - sites
  - orders
  - etc
```

The `account` will be part of the auth token, so my current plan is to just pass that `account` UUID into all the repository methods and subsequently, into the `getCollection` method.

```
fun findAll(accountId: String): FindPublisher<Site> {
    return getCollection(accountId).find()
}
 
private fun getCollection(accountId: String): MongoCollection<Site> {
    return mongoClient
        .getDatabase(accountId)
        .getCollection("sites", Site::class.java)
}
```

But I feel like that's clunky and there might be a more elegant way to do it. So just looking for suggestions.